# Derivative of the positive part of absolutely continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Question: Let $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be absolutely continuous. Show that $(f^+)' = f' \chi_{\{f >0\}}$ a.e.

My attempt: I am able to show that $f^+$ is absolutely continuous so $(f^+)'$ exists a.e. However, I am not sure how to formulate an argument to show the second part holds, let alone a.e. Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_0 \in (a, b)$ be a point where $f^+$ is differentiable.

If $f(x_0) > 0$ then $f^+(x_0) = f(x_0) > 0$ and $f^+$ is continuous at $x_0$, so that  $f^+(x) = f(x) > 0$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$. It follows that $(f^+)'(x_0) = f'(x_0)$.

If $f(x_0) \le 0$ then $f^+(x_0) = 0$ and
$$
 (f^+)'(x_0) = \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f^+(x)}{x-x_0} = 0
$$
because $\lim_{x \to x_0+} \frac{f^+(x)}{x-x_0} \ge 0$ and $\lim_{x \to x_0-} \frac{f^+(x)}{x-x_0} \le 0$.

This shows that  $(f^+)'(x) = f'(x) \chi_{\{f >0\}}(x)$ holds at all points $x \in (a,b)$ where $f^+$ and $f$ are differentiable, and that is a.e. in $[a, b]$.

Comment: Thank you! Great answer!